# Good, intuitive materials for learning Field of Quotients, Polynomial Rings and Factorization

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Its approaching end of term and my instructor for Algebra just sped through these three topics, pretending we understand. Can anyone who has taken this course before recommend some books and resources that explain this thing well by highlighting a few strong points and making the material more digestible? Is there a key relationship I should understand between these three topics? I am currently using Fraleigh and I am just so confused.

Comment: Try Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph A. Gallian. Though it is not very intuitive, but a good book can help you build your own. :)

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi I am taking algebra course right now and the instructor is using that book. I really didn't like how dry it is and it doesn't show the big picture. Also the topics are in weird sequence. Problems are good though.

Comment: OP, off topic but where do you study?

Comment: @khajvah: Yes, and if you have solved each and every exercise question, you have really strong concepts by the end of it. :)